# InvalidURIError when useing httparty post method and get the some field through users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

InvalidURIError (bad URI(is not URI?): https://api.flightstats.com/flex/schedules/rest/v1/json/from/VNS/to/DEL/departing/2017/
                       8/7?appId=94f56975&appKey=0a0dc2b64f177ab866f0dba59342ffa4)
how can solve this error.useing httparty post method.

flight =HTTParty.post("https://api.flightstats.com/flex/schedules/rest/v1/json/from/#{params[:from]}/to/#{params[:to]}/departing/#{params[:year]}/
                       #{params[:month]}/#{params[:day]}?appId=94f56975&appKey=0a0dc2b64f177ab866f0dba59342ffa4")

Comment: HTTParty.post("https://api.flightstats.com/flex/schedules/rest/v1/json/from/#{params[:from]}/to/#{params[:to]}/departing/#{params[:year]}/ #{params[:month]}/#{params[:day]}?appId=94f56975&appKey=0a0dc2b64f177ab866f0dba59342ffa4")

Comment: after remove white space.<HTTParty::Response:0x10 parsed_response=nil, @response=#<Net::HTTPMethodNotAllowed 405 Method Not Allowed readbody=true>, @headers={"server"=>["Apache-Coyote/1.1"], "allow"=>["HEAD,GET,OPTIONS"], "content-length"=>["0"], "date"=>["Sun, 06 Aug 2017 14:15:32 GMT"], "connection"=>["close"]}>

Comment: you are telling correct.than how to get the data our requirement because i am not use flightstats api..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems. First the URL includes a whitespace between `#{param‌​s[:year]}` and `#{params[:month]}` which leads to an invalid URL. The code tries a `POST` request, but according to their [documentation](https://developer.flightstats.com/api-docs/scheduledFlights/v1) that endpoint accepts `GET` requests.

Change your code to:

```
HTTParty.get(
  "https://api.flightstats.com/flex/schedules/rest/v1/json/from/"{params[:from]}/to/#{params[:to]}/departing/#{params[:year]}/#{params[:month]}/#{params[:day]}?appId=94f56975&appKey=0a0dc2b64f177ab866f0dba59342ffa4"
)
```

Comment: one question how to create the data array of hash in our database. multiple record are taken. how to create on by one. i am try like this.                response.each do |hash|    
      fs = hash[:fs]
     iata =hash[:iata]                                                     Airport.create!(fs: fs,iata: iata)
     render :json => response
  end

Comment: okk . but only one question are allowed that why am asking here.